# How can I align my camera with a very thin object?

Tags: technique, subject-positioning

I am trying to take pictures of a fluid interface touching a thin plate. This plate is 0.01 inch thick and 3 inches wide. I've included a sample image below.

Is there a good way to align my camera so that it looks at the thin edge of the plate dead on? I have managed to get close through trial and error but I don't really have a systematic way of doing it.

[image]

Comment: Are you measuring the meniscus of various fluids?

Comment: @stan yes, I'm trying to measure the contact angle

Comment: Don't forget that the plate must be vertical and perpendicular to the surface of the liquid. You did not specify perpendicularity which will affect your analysis

Comment: Anyone have suggestions for tags for this question? [tag:image-alignment] is about aligning multiple images for stacking or panoramic photographs...

Comment: @Stan The plate is suspended on a hinge so that gravity should ensure that it is perpendicular to the surface of the liquid

Comment: Use a laser to verify the perpendicularity by directing a level (easier to check), horizontal beam from a distance. The reflected beam should coincide with the source. "Should" doesn't cut it in your research paper.

Comment: @stan Thanks for the advice, I'll double check my with a laser

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a camera as a scientific measuring instrument, rather than to produce artistic photographs as the final intention. This question belongs on physics.SE because the basic problem the question attempts to solve is not about creative photography within the scope of this community.

Comment: @MichaelClark Strongly disagreed. The classic [Bullet through apple](https://americanart.si.edu/artwork/bullet-through-apple-32694) image is at the Smithsonian American Art Museum. Scientific imaging can be every bit as artistic as Ansel Adams's Moonrise, Hernandez, New Mexico.

Comment: There's a difference between using science to produce an image and using an image to produce science. Egerton's work was the former, this question is attempting to do the later. Egerton was doing all of his research to be able to make high speed photos, he wasn't making high speed photos to do research in another discipline.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things you can try.

1. Shine green light on one side of the plate and red on the other. When viewed from the edge-on, there will be none of the red or green visible from either of the sides. As a benefit, the predominating colour will indicate which direction to move the camera.
2. Using an interference pattern such as a moiré or speckle from a laser source. As you view the edge, the speckle pattern will become more coarse as you resolve the edge.

Comment: Thanks, I will try shining the two colored lights on either side

Answer (score 1):

A set of inexpensive macro focus rails will let you make fine left/right and forward/backward adjustments to the camera position. You'll still need to get the optical axis parallel with the plate, probably by loosing the mounting screw a bit and adjusting the camera. Once you've got it once, though, you can lock it down and use the rail adjustments to line the camera up laterally.

Also, using a longer lens will let you put the camera farther away. More distance means that you'll need to move the camera a greater linear distance for a given angular change, so adjustments don't have to be so precise. If you're using a 60mm macro lens, switching up to 100mm or 180mm will give you two or three times the distance, which should help make alignment easier. (And at 180mm and 1:1 magnification, you'll still only be ~18" from the subject.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Although as you mentioned, hardest part is getting the axis parallel to the plate. I will probably try and use a macro stage and the techniques described by Stan

Comment: @MrZ. Using a longer lens may help -- I've added that above.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting a flshlight behind the plate (if thats possible) and aligning the shadow on the center of your lense. This might work.